# Match a word if there a specific word in the sentence before

Tags: regex

I would like to match a word if there a specific word before in a sentence, for instance:

> test1 foo test2 bar

I would like to match `bar` if `foo` is in the sentence before (and/or after `bar`).

I tried:

```
(?<=(foo ([\w ]+)(?= bar)))bar
```

But doesn't work, the regex is incorrect because of `+` in lookbehind...

Could you please help me, thanks

Comment: Use two regexes: `if (/foo/ && /bar/)`

Comment: What's the regex flavor? If PCRE try [`^(?=.*?\bfoo\b).*?\K\bbar\b`](https://regex101.com/r/FUwwdj/1/)

Comment: The flavor is java

Comment: If you need to replace it, try [`^(?=.*?\bfoo\b)(.*?)\bbar\b`](https://regex101.com/r/FUwwdj/3) and replace with `$1replaced`. If you need to just match: [`^(?=.*?\bfoo\b).*?\bbar\b`](https://regex101.com/r/FUwwdj/5)

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use one regex, you can just simply move the `[\w ]+` out of the lookbehind. Then use an alternation to look for the word bar (on its own, not as part of another word) followed by foo as well:

```
((?<=foo)[\w ]+\bbar\b|\bbar\b[\w ]+(?=foo))
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/kcA7gd/8)

Comment: This regex match any word with bar, I would that it match only bar if there the word foo before, I don't know if it's reallypossible

Comment: Hi John sorry about that.  I've modified the regex so it will only match bar as a word on its own. See my edit

Comment: This regex will match every word and space after "foo", I think it's more something like:

(?<=(foo([\w ]+)))\bbar\b

Comment: What are you actually trying to match? the word foo? or bar? or ??? or just to see if the pattern matches when bar is in a string with foo, in which case what it actually matches doesn't matter.

Comment: Actually I didnt see the @booble bubble answer, but it's like this (match "bar" if "foo" is in the sentence): https://regex101.com/r/FUwwdj/1/
but with java flavor